# Delay Block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to create a delay block in simulink that has 3 options within it. The 3 options I want is a x, y, and z. I would like to be able to choose different types of statistical probability functions within each one. However, I am having a hard time finding in documentation on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the relation between `x`, `y` and `z` and the delay?

Comment: [Transport delay](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html)?

Comment: I am trying to create multiple parameters but I'm not sure how to do it. Right now under parameters I'll have x and then a subsets of other values but as soon as I try to add in y I get an error after applying my changes.